# Commented lines in crontab linux

Tags: shell, cron

I am looking for help to identify commented lines in crontab and which are not scheduled(even commented). i mean user commented lines with small description rather than uncommented scheduled line.

```
[oracle@test:]$: crontab -l
     #######-----------long running queries---------------#######
     * * * * * bash /home/oracle/crons/long_running.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
     ###*/7 * * * * rsync -az --bwlimit=8000 --rsh='sshpass -p bye ssh -l 
     oracle' oracle@test:/var/db_logs/logs/*.log /home/oracle/logs;
     ######-------one time execution backup database----------##########
     00 00 * * * bash /home/oracle/crons/db_backup.sh -param -full
```

---

In above crontab entries, below lines are commented lines that are merely comments with arbitrary text.

```
####-----------one time execution backup database----------#############
#########-----------long running queries-----------------##############
```

Un scheduled valid commented entries:

```
###*/7 * * * * rsync -az --bwlimit=8000 --rsh='sshpass -p bye ssh -l oracle' oracle@test:/var/db_logs/logs/*.log /home/oracle/logs;
```

I need to filter commented lines that are merely comments with arbitrary text.

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? What kind of algorithm do you have for differentiating between a commented cron entry and a simple comment?

Comment: @Glenn, Thank you for Quick response, i am generating html report based on  cron entries. i.e columns are frequency, script,status whether it is commented or un commented. in the report i am also getting these unwanted entries. (####-----------one time execution backup database----------#############
#########-----------long running queries-----------------##############). How to avoid these entries.....  i have 50 servers and i am generating report... in those 50 users users may put anything in comments.. any thoughts....

Comment: If you're trying to distinguish between (a) commented lines that would be valid entries of the comment delimiter were removed and (b) commented lines that are merely comments with arbitrary text, please update your question to make that clear. (There's no difference as far as `cron` is concerned.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to find all the lines that have the five crontab fields specifying day, time and so on, even if they are comments.  The following grep command does that:

```
crontab -l | grep ".*[0-9*/,-]\{1,\} [0-9*/,-]\{1,\} [0-9*/,-]\{1,\} [0-9*/,-]\{1,\} [0-9*/,-]\{1,\}"
```

Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Thank you very much , i got perfect output(commented lines that are merely comments with arbitrary text) with -v flag to your grep(grep ".*[0-9*]\{1,\} [0-9*]\{1,\} [0-9*]\{1,\} [0-9*]\{1,\} [0-9*]\{1,\}"). By the way, Can you please explain logic..?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.  If you're unfamiliar with regular expression syntax, you might want to look at this site: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Also, if you are happy with the answer, it is customary to accept it by clicking on the check mark icon to the left of the answer. :)

Comment: Sure Leslie, i worked on this today . But i am getting below line also as output if i use grep -v along with logic.
#00 11 1 */4 * bash do_report_java.sh -c java_application_config_file.sh  > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Oops. That's because I didn't allow for the "/" character in the fields.  I should have also allowed for the "," and "-" characters, since they are valid as well.  Try changing every "[0-9*]" to "[0-9*/,-]" and see if it works.